# Trouble appending the path directory in Python

Tags: python, path

The following script runs just fine for me:

```
def readData(fname):
    with open(fname, encoding="utf8") as f:
        read_data = f.read()
    return read_data

data = readData('D:/bar/foo.txt')
```

But when I try to run this:

```
from sys import path
path.append('D:/bar/')

def readData(fname):
    with open(fname, encoding="utf8") as f:
        read_data = f.read()
    return read_data

data = readData('foo.txt')
```

The "with" line produces this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.txt'
```

When I print **sys.path**, it does include the **bar** directory.

Why can't Python find my file? Is it necessary to specify the directory when loading it?

Comment: Did you try adding `//` instead of `/`?

Comment: Yes. Didn't help. Neither does changing foreslashes to backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bart mentioned, `sys.path` tells the interpreter where it should look for modules that you attempt to use via the `import` statement.

`sys.path` doesn't have anything to do with the built in `open()` function ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)).

The `file` argument you provide to the `open()` function should be an absolute path to the file, or a relative path from the working directory.

Your first example works because you have provided an absolute path to the file. Your second example (presumably) doesn't work because the script you are executing and `foo.txt` are not in the same directory (or if you are using the interpreter interactively, `foo.txt` isn't in the working directory).

Answer (score 0):

[`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) is the search path for modules. Your script tries to find the file in the current working directory (probably the dir you started your script in).

You can find that with [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your working directory.
I.e 
I'm using pycharm, so I'll describe how to do it here.
I just click on File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment 
--> Console --> Python Console.

And you set up your default working directory there
For example D:\dev\Python\your project_name